# Reading a file from a URI in logstash

Tags: logstash

I have a file sitting on a remote server.  I know the file by its URI:

`http://some.server/dir/derp/syslog.log`

When I use the logstash *file* input, the URI is rejected with an error complaining of a relative path.  There is no security on the remote file. I can `curl` it without issue from the logstash system.

My newb-config input snippet looks like:

```
input {
        file {
        path => "http://some.server/dir/derp/syslog.log"
        type => "syslog"
        }
```

What's the right way to read the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `file` input plugin doesn't read remote files, it only allows to read files from the local host.

You have a few solutions:

A. You can [install filebeat](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/index.html) on your remote server `some.server` to tail that syslog file and either ship it to your logstash or directly to your ES server.

B. You can install Logstash directly on your remote server and have the `file` input plugin tail that file directly on the server.

C. You can use the [`http_poller` input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http_poller.html) in order to retrieve that file via HTTP.

```
input {
  http_poller {
    urls => {
      mysyslog => "http://some.server/dir/derp/syslog.log"
    }
    request_timeout => 60
    interval => 60
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, just got back to work this morning. I'm reviewing it now. I saw somewhere that the `http_poller` option reads the entire file without regard to bits that have been read previously, so I must contemplate how I would make this work.  Due to my environment and that of my customer, I believe it will be the only option.  More to Come.

Comment: The most logical solution to me would be using A as C won't allow you to "tail" the syslog file. I thought you just wanted to download and process it at once.

Comment: Ideally, the file could be updated. I don't have access to my customer's servers, and to install things I have to run the gauntlet from the IT Security team.  So I may have to read the entire file, then discard the already read line myself. It's a small matter in the scheme of things. Trying this now.

Comment: Another option of course is to copy the file to my local machine and process it using `file{}` I am trying to avoid this...

Comment: Ok, got it, yes you could store the last read timestamp and then only process the newly downloaded file from that position.