# logstash reading file stream from a local network

Tags: logstash

I want to read files located in `Archive` folder in a local network. I tried this using the local IP of that machine but didn't work:

```
 file {
        path => "file://XXX.YYY.ZZZ.WWW/Archive/*"

  }
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40551740/reading-a-file-from-a-uri-in-logstash/40559967

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use filebeat for this?

Comment: No problem to use filebeat, still need to install filebeat on where data exists but i look for a solution to access data from filebeat/logstash in other machine that in local domain